# How do i test a module that extends my controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I wanted to create a module because i needed to execute some methods upon every controller action of my application. Thus, i created a module and used a before_filter to my application controller, so that it runs for every action.

This module is like a controller extension, since it handles redirects and has some methods as well. I need to have a logged in user to check that, but for some reason, the macro that i have for my other controllers is not recognized :

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'devise/test_helpers'

describe GameEngine::GameLoop do
    login_user

    it "should check tavern quest" do
        ...
    end

end
```

I get that login_user is undefined, though it works for all my controller, where i need it. Why isn't it recognized on the module ?

Comment: If this is rspec, you may need to define a module that extends rspec, not your controller.

Comment: im not sure i understand this. Could you please give an example ?

Comment: The `login_user` method is called in the context of the test as far as I understand, not the context of the active controller instance. You should probably tag this question with the testing framework used.

Comment: I don't think this is what is happening, because i get login_user undefined. It seems like the macro is not read for some reason.

Comment: You're calling `login_user` in the context of the test, that's where the method is expected to be, but it is defined in the controller as far as I can tell. Most frameworks like Devise will create a special testing method that hooks into `Test::Unit` or others. If you want to know what methods are defined, check the output of `puts (self.methods - Object.new.methods).sort.inspect` to see methods available for that context.

Comment: Oh, so if i get it correctly it's not read by controller_macros.rb ? Hmm, i think i've used it in my models as well. The thing is that even if i used it in a before_each block, i still get back an undefined.